# Solr full import with multicores

Tags: solr, multicore

I'm trying to create a Solr machine with multiple cores.
At the moment, my problem is performing the initial full import. The first core imports perfectly. However, when I try to import the second core, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock obtain timed out: NativeFSLock@/home/solr/solr/data/index/write.lock
        at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:84)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:602)
        at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:75)
        at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:62)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:191)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:77)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:157)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processAdd(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:61)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor.processAdd(UpdateRequestProcessor.java:51)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.doLocalAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:432)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.versionAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:557)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.DistributedUpdateProcessor.processAdd(DistributedUpdateProcessor.java:325)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processAdd(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:100)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.SolrWriter.upload(SolrWriter.java:70)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler$1.upload(DataImportHandler.java:233)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:507)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.buildDocument(DocBuilder.java:411)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.doFullDump(DocBuilder.java:326)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:234)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:382)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:448)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:429)
Feb 25, 2013 11:54:30 AM org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder execute
```

This happens on the second core, regardless on which one I start with.
What am I missing here? Each core runs perfectly on its own.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the index dir for both cores is the same. As soon as you start a full import for one core, there is a write.lock file in that dir, which won't be deleted until the import completes. You anyway want to keep the indexes for the cores in separate dirs, so modify solrconfig.xml like this:

```
  <!-- Used to specify an alternate directory to hold all index data
       other than the default ./data under the Solr home.
       If replication is in use, this should match the replication 
       configuration. -->
  <dataDir>./data/${solr.core.name}</dataDir>
```

Comment: but what about it you want to make a backup core and want to swap the cores via the admin.. this approach may lead to issues.